# CreateFile returns Access_Denied in Win10

Tags: windows, winapi

CreateFile() returns ACCESS_DENIED in Windows10 when i try in my project. If i create sample application using CreateFile() it works fine. Even tried to check admin privileges before calling CreateFile(), user is in admin mode. Same code works fine in Win 7.

Below is code sample:

```
 WCHAR userPath[] = L"C:\\test.txt";
 HANDLE hFile = NULL;

 hFile = ::CreateFile(userPath,
 GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
 0,
 NULL,
 CREATE_ALWAYS,
 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
 NULL);

 if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
    wprintf(L"Error HANDLE = 0x%x \n",hFile);
 }
 else
 {
    wprintf(L"Suceess HANDLE = 0x%x \n",hFile);
    ::CloseHandle(hFile);
 }
```

Comment: Clearly your user doesn't have sufficient rights to create a file there.

Comment: have you checked, if you can create a file manually there? have you tried if it works with another path?

Comment: You cannot create files in C:\ drive root folder.

Comment: Yes manually I am able to create a file in "C:\" location.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious explanation is that your user simply does not have sufficient rights to create files at the root level of the system drive.

Since Windows 7, and possibly even Vista, the default security configuration of the system drive permits standard user to create folders at the root level, but not files. So, my hypothesis is that you are not running your process elevated as you claim, but are in fact running the process with standard user rights. In order for you to create a file at that location you will need to either:

1. Run the process with elevated rights, or
2. Modify the security settings of the volume.

Comment: Third option: Acquire an impersonation [Access Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909.aspx) that has the required permissions, and assign it to the thread performing the operation.

Comment: @IInspectable Isn't that going to involve UAC elevation at some point along the way?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can call [AcceptSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374703.aspx) and pass in the required credentials without using a UAC prompt. A subsequent call to [ImpersonateSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375497.aspx) adjusts the security context of the target thread. The advantage is, that you do not have to re-launch the process to get a UAC prompt, and that it only affects a single thread (that can exit upon completion).

Comment: Edit: [InitializeSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375506.aspx) rather than [AcceptSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374703.aspx).

Comment: I am checking if the process has Admin rights mode before calling CreateFile. And also this fails in IE only with ActiveX, with java plugin CreateFile is working fine.

Comment: It's as I said. You don't have sufficient rights. The question isn't about IE.

Answer (score 0):

I was running my application in browser. There was issue with IE settings. When i disabled protected mode from IE->Security->Enable protected Mode, CreateFile() worked. Another solution is adding the ip to trusted site in IE.